# POST converting to GET during ajax call

Tags: javascript, java, http

I have an application where there could be anywhere between 1 - 30 POST ajax calls happening in parallel. Also these calls are being made to the same method in the controller.

But when there are more number of ajax calls, for some of the calls, I get status `307 Internal Redirect` and it gets converted to GET. And since the method in the controller does not have a type GET, I get a `405 method not allowed` error.

I am looking for the cause and unable to find one. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's your back end? Java? PHP? Are you using a load balancer?

Comment: "It gets converted to GET". By whom? Which browser?

Comment: "It gets converted to GET". Redirected to what URL?

Comment: The back end is java.  I am using google Chrome at the moment.

Comment: I just saw that 307 and 405 errors in the network tab of chrome. It doesnt specify who converts the request to GET or which URL it gets redirected to internally.

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen with all browsers?

[When HTTP 307, the caller should repeat the request using the same HTTP verb](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect). However it seems as usual [IE prefers do its thing](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/51130098-155b-4fcb-a404-342416e7f8b6/ie-789-dont-redirect-with-307-correctly-when-started-by-javascript?forum=iewebdevelopment).

Note that it would be interesting to find out why is that HTTP 307 happening as well.

Comment: I just tested for this issue and it is happening only in Google Chrome. Firefox and IE versions 8-11 handle it without any issues.